# I'm with this Error in my code: Exception caught by gestures library Cannot hit test a render box with no size

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#5a90d relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:

Exception caught by gestures library
Cannot hit test a render box with no size.

```
double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF101d25),
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      height: deviceHeight,
      color: const Color(0xFF101d25),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 110),
            child: Text(
              'Welcome to WhatsApp',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, bottom: 70),
            child: Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/image_whatsapp.jpg',
                  height: 260,
                  width: 260,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
            child: RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                const TextSpan(
                    text: 'Read our ',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                TextSpan(
                    text: 'Privicy Police',
                    style:
                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () {
                        // print('CLICK TAP ');
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Privicy Police'),
                                content: const Text(
                                    'This is a test to show a Alert dialog...'),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: const Text('Agree'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: const Text('Disagree'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      }),
                const TextSpan(
                  text: ' Tap "Agree and continue" to accept the ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                    text: 'Terms of Service',
                    style:
                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () {
                        //print('CLICK AGREE');
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text('Terms of Service'),
                                content: const Text(
                                    'This is a test to show a Alert dialog...'),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: const Text('Agree'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: const Text('Disagree'),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                      }),
                const TextSpan(
                  text: '.',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 480,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _dialogBuilder(context);
                    //('AGREE AND CONTINUE');
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0ca886)),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      'AGREE AND CONTINUE',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF121a21), fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "From",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Text("FACEBOOK",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. I _do_ have a different error message of: ```Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget```

Comment: Yes, every time that I place a singleScrollView it gives me this error… What can this be?

Comment: You shouldn't put column inside expanded, You should use Expanded only within a Column, Row or Flex

Answer (score 0):

Base on the code you shared, it looks like you've used the Expanded widget  wrongly in one of the items. Here is the corrected version below. Let me know if this solved your issue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main () {
  
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF101d25),
            body: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: deviceHeight,
                color: const Color(0xFF101d25),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 110),
                      child: Text(
                        'Welcome to WhatsApp',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 35,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                    // The change is here
                   Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, bottom: 70),
                          child:
                          SizedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'images/image_whatsapp.jpg',
                            height: 260,
                            width: 260,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
                      child: RichText(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                          const TextSpan(
                              text: 'Read our ',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'Privicy Police',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  // print('CLICK TAP ');
                                  showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          title: const Text('Privicy Police'),
                                          content: const Text(
                                              'This is a test to show a Alert dialog...'),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: const Text('Agree'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: const Text('Disagree'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                                }),
                          const TextSpan(
                            text: ' Tap "Agree and continue" to accept the ',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'Terms of Service',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  //print('CLICK AGREE');
                                  showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          title: const Text('Terms of Service'),
                                          content: const Text(
                                              'This is a test to show a Alert dialog...'),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: const Text('Agree'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            TextButton(
                                              child: const Text('Disagree'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              },
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                                }),
                          const TextSpan(
                            text: '.',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 480,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
//                     _dialogBuilder(context);
                              //('AGREE AND CONTINUE');
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0ca886)),
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                              child: Text(
                                'AGREE AND CONTINUE',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF121a21), fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "From",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            Text("FACEBOOK",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  letterSpacing: 3,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: I put sizes in all containers and sizeBoxs,
I switched to this, but now it doesn't adapt to screen rotation. My idea is to adjust it to use on any screen both landscape and on portrait different phone models, keeping the default values.

Comment: I'm having difficulty building a screen that would be adaptive.

Comment: Great that it resolved the issue but it seems you'd have to create another question regarding adaptability regarding screen rotation. I believe the answer solved the question you asked.